# Authorization code for access control

Tags: angularjs

How to write a angularjs  code to check if the value passing is already exist in the array and if exists, user should be given access rights, if not, he should not be given rights

Comment: Do you mean to check the value in a simple javascript array or JSON array? Please add more details to this question.

Comment: its a json array which has two fields in it named roles and accessName. when a user clicks on the button in UI (for example add button for account addition)accessName: ''ACCOUNT_ADD"

Comment: {accessName: ''ACCOUNT_ADD", roles:['ADMIN','MANAGER']}                                                                                           ----Json array

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: it should fetch user role from session and accessName from privilege collection and check if that particular accessName has the current user role in array. If so the user should be given permission to add account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work

In your HTML you need to bind the `ng-click` with a button that will check the privilege and perform accordingly. Lets say the button is like this

```
<button type="button" ng-click="checkPrivilege();">Check Privilege</button>
```

Inside your controller you need to do some operations like this

```
//say, this is our privilege JSON
$scope.privilege = [
                    {
                     accessName: "ACCOUNT_ADD", 
                     roles:['ADMIN','MANAGER']
                    },
                    {
                     accessName: "ACCOUNT_DELETE", 
                     roles:['ADMIN']
                    }
                ];

$scope.checkPrivilege = function(){
    //first you need to find out the role of the logged in user, lets say 
    //you get the role value from getLoggedInUserRole() function
    $scope.userRole = getLoggedInUserRole();

    //lets say the selected access name is 'ACCOUNT_ADD'
    $scope.allowedAccessName = "ACCOUNT_ADD";

    angular.forEach($scope.privilege, function(value, key) {

        var privilegedRoles = privilege[key].roles;
        var privilegedAccessName = privilege[key].accessName;

        //check if the json object contains the same accessName which we need
        if($scope.allowedAccessName === privilegedAccessName){
         //check if the role is allowed or not for this user
         if( privilegedRoles.indexOf(userRole) > -1 ){
            //the logged in user has this privilege to accessName
            break;
         }else{
            // the logged in user has no access to this accessName
         }
        }
    });
}
```

You can look at the comment and understand. This code may not be exactly the same which you are expecting but you will surely get an idea about how you can achieve your goal.